# django app doesn't find mysql database on docker

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

I am a noobie and I used some different tutorials to satisfy my needs for a project I'm working on.
when I use the command (docker-compose run  app sh -c "python manage.py test && flake8") it gives me the following error(s):

```
Starting base-project_db_1 ... 
Starting base-project_db_1 ... error

ERROR: for base-project_db_1  Cannot start service db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint base-project_db_1 (7643b9adae37916dc14eba4f000a44d6bb8238b43c9c43044d283801c46bb41f): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint base-project_db_1 (7643b9adae37916dc14eba4f000a44d6bb8238b43c9c43044d283801c46bb41f): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 233, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 53, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 687, in run_tests
    self.run_checks()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 625, in run_checks
    call_command('check', verbosity=self.verbosity)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 168, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/check.py", line 59, in handle
    self.check(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 34, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1275, in check
    *cls._check_constraints(),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1841, in _check_constraints
    connection.features.supports_table_check_constraints or
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py", line 93, in supports_column_check_constraints
    if self.connection.mysql_is_mariadb:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 363, in mysql_is_mariadb
    return 'mariadb' in self.mysql_server_info.lower()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 350, in mysql_server_info
    with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 604, in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 260, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 236, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 233, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)")
```

my django settings:

```
'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASS'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT'),
    }
```

docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
    app:
        build:
            context: .
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
            - ./app:/app
        command: >
            sh -c "python manage.py migrate &&
                   python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
        environment:
            - DB_HOST=db
            - DB_NAME=*
            - DB_USER=*
            - DB_PASS=*
            - DB_PORT=3306
        depends_on:
            - db

    db:
        image: mysql:8.0.20
        command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        volumes:
            - "./mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        restart: always
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=*
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=*
            - MYSQL_USER=*
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=*
```

the mySQL container logs:

```
2020-05-13 08:21:07+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
2020-05-13 08:21:07+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-05-13 08:21:07+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
2020-05-13T08:21:08.004909Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2020-05-13T08:21:08.005016Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20) starting as process 1
2020-05-13T08:21:08.015303Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-05-13T08:21:11.686807Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-05-13T08:21:11.923548Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-05-13T08:21:12.058480Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2020-05-13T08:21:12.139149Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2020-05-13T08:21:12.482959Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-05-13T08:21:12.494044Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-05-13T08:21:12.531970Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.20'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-05-13T19:03:05.778495Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

and the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update --no-cache mariadb-dev jpeg-dev
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
        gcc libc-dev linux-headers python3-dev musl-dev zlib zlib-dev
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
RUN apk del .tmp-build-deps

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app

RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/media
RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/static
RUN adduser -D user
RUN chown -R user:user /vol/
RUN chmod -R 755 /vol/web
USER user
```

also if you have any suggestions for improvement please let me know,
any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that your mysql is not running. Check its container log.

Comment: @jweyrich I added a bit more. take another look, please.